# Xcode 5 and localization issue - how can I use the original language?

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, xcode5

I'm now building up an iOS application and tried to localize the app to the different language. However, when I add the new language to localize the application, and run the app simulator, the resultant simulator uses the new language.

That's OK, since I used the new language. However, am I no more able to use the original language and run the simulator..? I didn't find any such setting as "use the original language". So how can I do?

Also, if I add the new language, and modify the original language's layout, such as adding another button, function, class, etc..., does the change reflect in the setting of the new language too? Or do I have to bother modifying all of the language's layouts every time I'm forced to do so (then I know I should use localization until I finished up creating the app)?

I use iOS 7 and Xcode 5 on Mavericks for your information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the language of the simulator (in the general iPhone settings) to the language you want to see in your app.